# Java RMI не работает в интернете

Tags: java, rmi

Я только пробую работать с RMI. Запускаю клиент и сервер на разных компьютерах. Сначала запускал в одной локальной сети (по вифи) - все работало. Я решил попробовать запустить клиент и сервер в интернете (без общего вифи или провода), но мне выдало ошибку:

> java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 176.59.32.170; nested exception is: 
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Вот файлы, которые я использую:

- AddServerIntf.java

```java
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface AddServerIntf extends Remote {
    double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException;
}
```

- AddServerImpl.java

```java
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class AddServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AddServerIntf{

    public AddServerImpl() throws RemoteException{
    }

    @Override
    public double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException {
        return d1+d2;
    }
}
```

- AddServer.java

```java
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

public class AddServer {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "176.59.32.170");
            AddServerImpl obj = new AddServerImpl();
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            Naming.rebind("AddServer", obj);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Исключение: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

- AddClient.java

```java
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.util.*;

public class AddClient {

    static String kek = "176.59.32.170";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            String addServerURL = "rmi://"+kek+"/AddServer";
            AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf) Naming.lookup(addServerURL);
            double d1 = 3, d2 = 5;
            System.out.println("Первое число: "+d1+"\nВторое число: "+d2+"\nСумма: "+addServerIntf.add(d1, d2));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Исключение: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

На клиенте находятся следующие файлы: AddClient.java и AddServerIntf.java, а на сервере AddServer.java, AddServerImpl.java и AddServerIntf.java.
На клиенте, очевидно, запускаю AddClient.java, на сервере -- AddServer.java.

IP-адрес динамический (с мобильного интернета). В качестве IP для соединения использую именно его. При работе в локальной сети использовал адрес компьютера, который 192.168... .
Как сделать так, чтобы код работал посредством сети Интернет, исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Это значит, что между хостами нет маршрутизации или есть брандмауэры, блокирующие трафик, Java и RMI тут не при чём. Скорее всего, 176.59.32.170 NAT'ится шлюзом ОПСОСа, поэтому подключиться к нему невозможно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Купить белый IP-адрес, предварительно уточнив у провайдера, что они не будут блокировать входящие соединения и будут пропускать все виды трафика, а потом настроить сетевое оборудование и брандмауэр хоста на приём соединений.